# puting two class divs inside id div

Tags: html, css

I managed to achieve the design I want using this style of markup, tell me if this is good practice or not, I'm not sure if going deep with classes classifies as valit, but my tidy validator tells me all is ok.

```
<div id="main"> 

    <div class="submain">

        <div class="anothersub">text</div>

    </div>

</div>
```

and the css for this is

```
#main { width: 300px;}
#main .submain { width: 200px;}
#main .submain .anothersub { width: 100px;}
```

Comment: This type of question is probably better off on codereview.stackexchange, lest it be closed here as "not a real question" or "off topic".

Answer (score 2):

If your looking for an alternative, I think this would be better

```
#main { width: 300px;}
#main .submain { width: 66%;}
#main .submain .anothersub { width: 50%;}
```

Heres a fiddle, I put background colors so you can see
http://jsfiddle.net/v6ud2/

Comment: thanks! just a side question, how "deep" can i go with these classes? is it "semantic" to go #main .one .two .three .four .five .six .seven...or is this just dirty way of coding? :)

Comment: I don't see a problem, to make it organised you could give them id's like '<div id="submain">' then in the css just '#submain'.

When things get complex use Google Chrome's inspect element feature it makes it really clear to see each box, it's size etc.

Comment: You can go as far as you need, but in most case it should be less than ~15 nested divs.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing 'wrong' with your example at all, in many cases it will be just fine. However using IDs and using longer CSS selectors may make your code less scalable and because it's context specific, more difficult to maintain and harder to re-use.

I'd recommend reading [Harry Roberts CSS Wizardry blog](http://csswizardry.com/) if you're looking to create larger sites and re-usable code, in particular these articles:

- http://csswizardry.com/2012/07/shoot-to-kill-css-selector-intent/
- http://csswizardry.com/2012/10/a-classless-class-on-using-more-classes-in-your-html/
- http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/when-using-ids-can-be-a-pain-in-the-class/

Comment: thank you very much for the heads up, never saw that website before...some pretty heavy stuff there

Comment: It's very useful when you're building things that need to scale or need to evolve over several years. Don't get too hung up on methodologies introduced in the articles linked above, but you'll  write something in the future and there will be a click in the back of your mind that if you did the thing 'this way' it will save you time/effort/pain later ;)